# serving dynamically generated static img file in template django 1.6 dev server

Tags: python, django, image, syntax, static

I am trying to serve a static img file in a template that I have just had Django generate.  The template code looks like this.

```
<img src="{% static {{ output }} %}" height="50px" width="50px" alt="hi">
```

output is a context variable that I passed to the template through my views.  When I try and load the page I get this error.

Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value: Could not parse the remainder: '{{' from '{{'

obviously my syntax for passing a context variable to the static file method is flawed.  I am using the DJango 1.6 dev server and all of my other static files are working. Does anyone know the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need {{}} inside {% %}